# Whether an omega limit set of omega limit set of the plane can be a singular line

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

An autonomous system in $\mathbb{R}^2$, i.e. $\left\{ \begin{array} ax'=f(x,y)\\y'=g(x,y) \end{array}\right.$, such that for any point in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the equation satisfy the condition of existence and uniqueness (if possible, I hope f and g can be Lipschitz continuous).

Is it possible to construct such a system? There is a bounded omega limit set $\Omega_P$ for some $P\in\mathbb{R}^2$, and there is a $Q\in\Omega_P$ such that $\Omega_Q$ is **neither a closed orbits** (i.e. a continuous periodic solution) **or a single (singular) point**.

It's easy to prove that if $\Omega_Q$ contain an ordinary point then $\Omega_Q$ is a closed orbits. But I failed to "prove" the unexistance of the condition of which $\Omega_Q$ is a singular line.

Geometrily speaking, such kind of strange limit set of limit set exist, I wonder if the equation is truly exist and can be constructed...